# Paperclip :default_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a lot of files with `has_attached_file` method from paperclip but without `:default_url`; now I want to use the same image for all of them but I don't want to go from file to file and add this `:default_url` line for each file. There are some solution to set this in one place and will work for all the has_attached_file method calls?
I tried to do it in this way, but seems like it does not have any effect

```
module Paperclip
  module ClassMethods
    def has_attached_file(name, options = {})
      options[:default_url] => Rails.root + "/missing.png"
      HasAttachedFile.define_on(self, name, options)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are about to make it work – just change `options[:default_url] => Rails.root + "/missing.png"` to `options[:default_url] = Rails.root + "/missing.png"` (`=` instead of `=>`).

However, I suggest a better solution:

```
module Paperclip
  module ClassMethods
    def has_attached_file_with_preconfigured_default_url(name, options = {})
      options.reverse_merge! default_url: Rails.root + "/missing.png"
      has_attached_file_without_preconfigured_default_url(name, options)
    end
    alias_method_chain :has_attached_file, :preconfigured_default_url
  end
end

# Now you could use both new has_attached_file and old has_attached_file_without_preconfigured_default_url.
```

And place this code into initializer.